# Regex for decimal (square meter) values

Tags: c#, regex, decimal

I got a regex that fails on validating my input.

My regex: `\d{1,5}([\.,]\d{0,2})?`

It should validate square meters (decimal values) with a separator of either `.` or `,` and should allow up to five digits (and at least one) before the separator and up to two after it.

So it should accept:
1
1,0
1.0
12345
12345,10
12345.10

But not
.1
12345**6**
12345,12**3**

Comment: What is your regex currently failing on?

Comment: @Amber It fails on nearly everything... `1`, `3,5`, `1555,5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the group you're capturing, `([\.,]\d{0,2})?`, you allow the numbers to appear between `0` and `2` times, *however*, the entire group is marked as optional per the ending `?`. Because of this, the range should be set to `{1,2}` instead:

```
\d{1,5}([\.,]\d{1,2})?
```

If your input is specifically a number (and not a full sentence), I would also recommend adding a leading `^` and an ending `$`. This will force the regex to check from the start of the string to the end (respectively). The final regex should be:

```
^\d{1,5}([\.,]\d{1,2})?$
```

If you're using this regex for more than validation and also want to view the matched values, you should change the current group that's matching (the decimal portion) to a non-matching group (change `(` to `(?:`) and then add parentheses around the full regex:

```
^(\d{1,5}(?:[\.,]\d{1,2})?)$
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close. The correct regex for that behaviour would be:

```
^\d{1,5}(?:[\.,]\d{0,2})?$
```

A good tool for tinkering with Regex's for .Net: Expresso. http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Comment: Note that the backslash in `[\.,]` is unnecessary; `.` doesn't need to be escaped inside of character classes.